# Sybase IQ 16 week starting day - only works with from statement?

Tags: sql, date, sybase

By default weeks in Sybase IQ start on a Sunday. It is possible to change this through:

```
--set start of week to be on Monday
SET OPTION date_first_day_of_week =1;
```

When I try to check that this option has been set I do:

```
SELECT DOW( '2015/01/05')
-- 2
```

This should return 1.

So I try this:

```
SELECT DOW( '2015/01/05')
FROM stringer_bell.vials
WHERE ID = 111111111111111111;
```

-- 1

This gives the correct answer, it seems that this date function requires a from statement to return the correct value. Using the calendar functions in a select on its own could be useful for a stored procedure.

Why does this happen?

-- Edit1

It was pointed out that the option is `first_day_of_week` and not `date_first_day_of_week` which is the Sybase IQ 12 option name. However I still get this behaviour when using the correct option na. I tested this with SQL Workbench/J

Comment: The option is called "first_day_of_week", not "date_first_day_of_week". Is it possible you're setting the wrong option in one of these two cases? I just tried this (with the correct option name) and it worked as expected.

Comment: I get the same behaviour when I use first_day_of_week. I will update the questions.

Answer (score 0):

[In Sybase IQ (prob all versions, certainly since 15) there are two table "catalog stores":](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_IQ/a898e08b84f21015969fa437e89860c8/a5c6aebd84f21015b22b92ead60dabde.html?q=iq_dummy)

1. IQ = the core columnar data store
2. SQl Anywhere = the other SAP architecture (most if not all the the sys tables are stored here)

So if you run without a from clause (or from the sys tables!), you end up in SQL Anywhere, and you may or may not get the same results as Sybase IQ;

*note: depending on how you score it, other engines/modes are available like Row level versioning (RLV aka TLV (transaction)) which lets you avoid table level locks and get something closer to OLTP, maybe others too.

Note the [official documentation for SAP IQ](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_IQ?locale=en-US&state=PRODUCTION&version=16.1.5.0) so you can avoid landing on SQL Anywhere results (where google seems to always send me).
Also learn the diff between WATCOM vs TSQL (different IF/THEN syntax)